# Can I use the word *Lost* as a verb?

Tags: sentence-construction, verbs

Can we use word *Lost* as Verb?
Like below sentence

"Oh I think we have lost in the Jungle"

"Oh I think we are lost in the jungle"

Or is there any other way to say?

Comment: I'm very inclined to say **what have you tried**. Have you checked any dictionaries on whether it can?

Comment: Second sentence "Oh! I think we *are* lost in the jungle" seems fine.

Comment: You could say "we are lost" or "we have gotten lost", but either way "lost" is an adjective. On the other hand,  "We lost our way in the jungle" uses **lost** as a verb

Answer (score 1):

Sentence 2 is good, however it uses "lost" as an adjective not a verb.

Sentence 1 is incorrect. You can use lost as a verb (past-tense of lose) but it needs an object. You could say

> I think we have lost our keys in the jungle.

Our even

> I think we have lost ourselves in the jungle.

Comment: 1) could be correct: "Oh I think we have lost [the match] in the Jungle"

Comment: @Glorfindel But *lose* is a transitive verb, so if you omit *the match* you must supply a pronoun to fill its syntactical slot: *I think we have lost **it** in the jungle*.

Comment: Good point Gorfindel! @StoneyB I disagree. "Lose" *can* take an object, but I don't think it has to. Look at 24 on this page http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lose

Comment: @Glorfindel ah, now I understand you. Yes, you are right: *lose* can be deployed without an explicit object provided that an implicit object (the game, the struggle, money) is apparent from the context. ... But I don't think that works where the sense is *become lost*, even if the context makes it clear that the intended object is *ourselves* or *our way*.